# update one particukar item in recyclerview from fragment after success response android kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

Fragment Recyclerview code :

```
private fun initRecyclerView() {

bestSellersAdapter = BestSellerProductsAdapter(frag)
        homeBinding.popularproductsRView.apply {
            bestSellersAdapter.second(this@HomeFragment)
            adapter = bestSellersAdapter
        }
}

    private fun getSection() {
          viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                roomProductVM.productFlow.collectLatest {
                    if (it.isEmpty()) {
                        categoryViewModel.getAllCategories()
                    } else {
                        bestSellersAdapter.setMutableArraylist(it)
                        bestSellersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

based on condition i call this function(getSection) in onViewCreated

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

      initRecyclerView()
      getSection()

addcartviewModel.cartTableSuccessorNot.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if(it.toInt() == variant_id) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Product Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() homeBinding.popularproductsRView.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(productPosition)
            } else {
                LoadingUtils.hideDialog()
                Toast.makeText(context,"Failure in Cart Table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}
```

interface function in fragment : ( here i am taking product position from adapter )

```
     override fun updatepro(position: Int, type: String, id: Int, cart_count: Int, is_notify: Boolean, product_id: Int, name: String, measurement: String,
                           variant_image: String, price: String, qty: String, stock: String, image: String, moq: String, unit: String) {
        productPosition = position
        variant_id = id
        variant_qty = qty.toInt()
        addcartviewModel.updateVariantTableinRoom(id,cart_count.toString(),is_notify,product_id)
addcartviewModel.insertVariantListintoCartTable(id,measurement,price,stock,image,moq,name,variant_image,unit,qty)
    }
```

Adapter class :

```
    class BestSellerProductsAdapter(var context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BestSellerProductsAdapter.BestSellerViewHolder>() {

var mutableList = mutableListOf<ProductWithVariants>()

    fun setMutableArraylist(datas: MutableList<ProductWithVariants>) {
        mutableList.clear()
        mutableList.addAll(datas)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BestSellerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
     var cart_count = mutableList[position].variantsList[0].cart_count
    
    if(stock?.toInt()==0) {
               holder.notify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.addtocart.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.pll_cart.visibility = View.GONE
            } else if(cart_count == 0) {
                holder.addtocart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.pll_cart.visibility = View.GONE
                holder.notify.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                    holder.notify.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.addtocart.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.pll_cart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    holder.tv_cart.text = cart_count.toString()
            }
    
    holder.addtocart.setOnClickListener {
                cart_count = ((cart_count ?: 0) + 1)
                selectpro?.updatepro(position,"AddCart",mutableList[position].variantsList[0].id,mutableList[position].variantsList[0].cart_count!!.toInt(),false,mutableList[position].products.id,
                    mutableList[position].products.name.toString(),
                    mutableList[position].variantsList[0].measurement.toString() + mutableList[position].variantsList[0].measurement_unit_name.toString(),
                    mutableList[position].variantsList[0].image.toString(),
                    mutableList[position].variantsList[0].discounted_price.toString(),
                    cart_count.toString(),
                    stock.toString(),
                    mutableList[position].variantsList[0].image.toString(),
                    moq.toString(),
                    mutableList[position].variantsList[0].measurement_unit_name.toString()
                )
            }
    
    var selectpro: selectproduct?=null
    
        fun second(selectproduct: selectproduct) {
            selectpro = selectproduct
        }
    
        interface selectproduct {
            fun updatepro(position:Int,type:String,id:Int, cart_count:Int,is_notify:Boolean,product_id:Int,
                          name:String,measurement:String,variant_image:String,price:String,qty:String,
                          stock:String,image:String,moq:String,unit:String)
            fun selectProduct(product: ProductWithVariants,position:Int)
        }
```

Now i want to update the particular item of recycler view after Toast ( Product Updated Successfully ) in fragment .. how to do that

Answer (score 0):

1  After response first find out the item position you want to update
in adapter

2 Also you have to update the list in adapter with new list of data
you get from the response.

then use below code to update particular item in adapter using
position.

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Comment: i am not having new list from response just success or failure is getting ..so that i can change the value of an item from fragment ..also notifyItemChnaged(position) is not working @Ravi Sharma

Comment: ok, may be the reason notifyItemChnaged(position) is not working because your list in adapter for "position" is not updated data. you have to update the data of list on success or failure for that particular position you want to update. And then call this method notifyItemChnaged(position) @SasidharanIOS